# Openbravo Error when trying to generate computed columns

Tags: open-source, erp, openbravo

I'm developing manufacturing management module, when i fished the development, all windows worked great, but I need to make some field to computed automatically.

So when I write a SQL command I get an error saying "You can't generate computed field", can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of me solve the problem, it's need to re build, so enter the command in terminal and solve the problem,, the command is:
ant smartbuild